# Disable focus for control in UWP

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am building a UWP app for a RPi3 with touchsreen. I have a textbox that I give focus to on page load. I don't want to lose that focus if a user touches another control on the page, except for two specific buttons. I am using this textbox for scanner input.

I've tried disabling different properties for the controls I don't want to get focus:

```
AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False"
```

But if I press any of those controls, the textbox stills loses focus.

I've also tried an event handler for textbox_LostFocus to re-give it focus, however this stops the user from clicking one the 2 buttons the user needs to click (the only controls who should receive focus) as the textbox_LostFocus event fires again to set the focus back to the textbox before the button_Click event can fire.

In a winform, I would have disabled the tabstop property. Any ideas for UWP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thankyou. Placing AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" in a Winui 3 Parent Window head xaml stops it focusing over child Windows when the child is opened from the parent. Before I added the line, the parent would cover the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your TextBox will not lose focus, you should be able to set the focus by the `Focus` method in the `LostFocus` event.

As you may know, if we set the `Focus` in the `LostFocus` event, the `Click` event will not be fired.

So we should be able to add an `if` in your `LostFocus` event, when the user clicks the Button, the Text can lose focus. To do that, we can add `PointerEntered` event and `PointerExited` of the `Button`. In the `PointerEntered` event, we can set the value of `setFocus`.

For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Click" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False"></Button>
        <TextBox Name="MyText" Text="Hello" LostFocus="MyText_LostFocus"></TextBox>
        <Button Name="MyButton" PointerEntered="MyButton_PointerEntered" PointerExited="MyButton_PointerExited" Click="Button_Click" Content="Submit"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private bool setFocus = true;

private void MyText_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (setFocus == true)
    {
        MyText.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyButton.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}

private void MyButton_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    setFocus = false;
}

private void MyButton_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    setFocus = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`IsEnabled` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_IsEnabled) does this. If you don't like the "greyed out" look, you can change the control template.

Answer (score 0):

On the buttons you don't want to focus on, try setting the `IsTabStop` property to `false`

Comment: (this property is also in UWP)

Comment: [IsTabStop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_IsTabStop) *"indicates whether a control is included in tab navigation."* In other words, this controls **keyboard** navigation. This is not what the question is asking for.

Comment: Oh i thought he meant keyboard focus since it's impossible to push the buttons if they don't have focus, he also said that in winforms he would use the isTabStop property so i'm just pointing out this is also available in uwp

Comment: Also, another solution would be to set the focus back on the textview in the clickhandler of the buttons

Comment: Again, this is not, what the OP is asking for. They are explicitly allowing those two button controls to take focus.

Comment: There is no other way. Workarounds are sometimes the only solution

Comment: [AllowFocusOnInteraction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_AllowFocusOnInteraction) set to `false` sounds like way less of a hack to me.

Comment: Look at the question before you comment please, he already tried that

Comment: I see a `"False"` there. Isn't XML inherently case-sensitive?

Comment: property values always start with a capital letter in XAML

Comment: I wonder why the AllowFocusInteraction is not working though. I also had this problem a few times before

Comment: I will check on MSDN to see if someone comes up with something. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours.

Solution in my case was setting root visual element (ScrollViewer) property AllowFocusOnInteraction to false:

```
var rootScrollViewer = GetVisualRootElement();
rootScrollViewer.AllowFocusOnInteraction = false;
```

My visual tree looks like this: ScrollViewer->Border->Frame->MainPage->StackPanel->etc...

Next step is setting AllowFocusOnInteraction to True to controls which you want to allow focus on interaction (TextBox, CheckBox etc...).

Best regards,

Adam